# problem with scons in windows

Tags: python, scons

I tried to build an executable for a python script using scons, which is failing with the following trace:

```
C:\WORKAREA\study>C:\Python26\Scripts\scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: warning: No installed VCs
File "C:\WORKAREA\study\SConstruct", line 1, in <module>

scons: warning: No version of Visual Studio compiler found - C/C++ compilers most likely not set correctly
File "C:\WORKAREA\study\SConstruct", line 1, in <module>
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
link /nologo /OUT:fibo.exe fibo.py
'link' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: *** [fibo.exe] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

It seems that *link /nologo /OUT* is the point where everything breaks down. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you add the directory that contains `VCs` to you `%path%` ?

Comment: Ross, don't have VC installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to build a .exe file from a .py file right? In that case, you don't need the VC++ compiler, you will need a tool like py2exe. And if you want to use SCons as a build system, you will need to create a SCons builder for py2exe.exe. Something along the lines as:

```
env = Environment()

def py2exe_action(target, source, env):
  # execute py2exe <source> <output> here
  return 0

env['BUILDERS']['Py2Exe'] = env.Builder(action = py2exe_action)
env.Default(env.Py2Exe(target = 'out_exe_file.exe', source = 'in_python_file.py'))
```

http://www.py2exe.org/

Comment: I did try py2exe. The problem it gave was that it was missing one/two imported files. Hence after py2exe had completed execution, and I executed the exe from command prompt, I'd get a import error.

Comment: As far as I know py2exe is the only free solution that can convert a .py file to a .exe file on windows. If you provide some details about the error (probably in a separate question since that isn't related to SCons anymore) maybe we can help you out fix the problem with py2exe.